# Adding orderby url parameter to main CPT admin menu link

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

Is it possible to change the main admin menu link for a CPT (the link to edit.php) to include URL parameters?

I wan't to make the posts list default to sorting by "title" but I don't like how updating the main query to force a "default" order doesn't set column header to reflect it.

If you click on the "Title" column header it adds the "orderby" url parameter so I'm wondering if there is a hook/filter that would allow me to append this to the menu link.

I can't see how this could be done when registering the new post type and would prefer not to use javascript to add it on after the page has loaded.

Comment: You could probably use `pre_get_posts` to identify when you are viewing that CPT, and `is_admin()` to make sure you are on the admin side, and then change `orderby`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `$_GET` directly inside your `pre_get_posts` action to get the UI to pickup that change:

```
function wpd_test_pre_get( $query ) {
    // put whatever conditions to target your cpt here
    if( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        // modify query
        $query->set('orderby', 'title');
        $query->set('order', 'asc');
        // set $_GET vars
        $_GET['orderby'] = 'title';
        $_GET['order'] = 'asc';
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_test_pre_get' );
```

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought that because pre_get_posts is run before the UI is generated then I could just set $_GET. I had to add `if !isset($_GET['orderby'])` to stop it from totally overriding the other sortable columns.